# Pixel randomly turn on flashlight, shows emergency call screen

Tags: bugs, google-pixel-6

This is a very poorly-defined question, because I can't figure out what causes this issue. But on occasion (and not rarely), when I pull my phone out of my pocket, the flashlight is on, bluetooth has been turned off, and when I unlock the phone I am looking at the emergency call screen. I believe that the DND and bedroom settings get modified sometimes as well.

I haven't been able to find anything like this on the web. Any ideas? (Pixel 6, Android 13)

Comment: I did and it seems to have worked. I've been waiting to see the behavior, and after about a week I have not had the problem. Thanks. If you want to write up an answer we can close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** In the lock screen settings disable both Tap to Wake and Lift to Wake

**Source:** [Pixel 6 Dialing Contacts Or Opening Random Apps When In Pocket [Fixed]](https://droidwin.com/pixel-6-dialing-contacts-or-opening-random-apps-when-in-pocket-fixed/)

> Numerous users have [voiced their concern](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/xdo7v7/comment/ioc507c/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) that whenever their Pixel 6 is kept in their pocket, it tends to open any random app, dial a phone call to any random person, enable DND Mode, turn on Airplane Mode, send a message via WhatsApp, etc

OP has [confirmed](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/252967/pixel-randomly-turn-on-flashlight-shows-emergency-call-screen?noredirect=1#comment342944_252967) the solution to work on their phone